# Measuring the speed of an object

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, relative-motion

If I understand correctly someone said (Einstein?) that all motion is relative. However, if it were possible; given that light always travels in a vacuum at a fixed speed, could all other motion be measured against this to give a real value to the motion of all objects?

Comment: Einstein has said, that you can't tell which frame of reference is moving, and which is not, that's true. evaluate, what kind of measurement are you interesting it

Answer (score 0):

> given that light always travels in a vacuum at a fixed speed, could all other motion be measured against this to give a real value to the motion of all objects ?

No. Even though light in a vacuum always travels at the same speed in any inertial frame, the velocity of anything traveling at a speed other than light-speed will be be different in different inertial frames.